# MSU File association

Tags: windows-7, file-association

In WindOS 7 x64, MSU file type is associated with WUSA.exe under System32 folder.

I made a <strike>big</strike> mistake by changing it to Explorer.exe under Windows folder.

Now, I cannot revert back the file association permanently. The  `Always use the selected program to open this kind of file` checkbox is disabled under Open with | Choose default program.

I tried to delete the registry entry (HKCR | .msu) but no luck.

Is there any fix for it (other of reinstalling Windows)?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Registry contains a list of all the file associations, specifically the "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT" section. Deleting the entry will not fix the issue as that makes it not connected to anything. What I think you need to do is set the key(s) back to its original values.

BTW I exported the key for the .MSU key from my Windows 7 Home Premium computer which should still be at the default value. Should be able to plop this into Notepad and save it with a .REG and then run it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.msu]
@="Microsoft.System.Update.1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.System.Update.1]
@="Microsoft Update Standalone Package"
"FriendlyTypeName"=hex(2):40,00,22,00,25,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,\
  00,72,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,\
  33,00,32,00,5c,00,77,00,75,00,73,00,61,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,2c,\
  00,2d,00,31,00,30,00,32,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.System.Update.1\CurVer]
@="Microsoft.System.Update.1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.System.Update.1\DefaultIcon]
@=hex(2):22,00,25,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,72,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,\
  00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,77,00,\
  75,00,73,00,61,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,2c,00,2d,00,31,00,30,00,31,\
  00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.System.Update.1\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.System.Update.1\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.System.Update.1\shell\open\command]
@=hex(2):22,00,25,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,72,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,\
  00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,77,00,\
  75,00,73,00,61,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,31,00,22,\
  00,20,00,25,00,32,00,20,00,25,00,33,00,20,00,25,00,34,00,20,00,25,00,35,00,\
  20,00,25,00,36,00,20,00,25,00,37,00,20,00,25,00,38,00,20,00,25,00,39,00,00,\
  00
```

Comment: Tried that. Unfortunately, it didn't permanently changed the association and the *Always use the selected program to open this kind of file* checkbox is disabled.

Comment: @vulcanraven: Try the extended registry export above and see if it helps.

Comment: @Karan, still the same and the checkbox is disabled.

Comment: @vulcanraven: You shouldn't need the *Always use the selected program to open this kind of file* checkbox since the registry edit ought to have set the association back to defaults. After importing did you reboot and then try running an MSU file? Odd it didn't work; I can't see anything else related to .MSU association in the registry.

Comment: @Karan, yes I did and its still associated with explorer.